# How to avoid adding all fields in @XmlType propOrder and also import the fields from parent class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xmltype

I am trying to marshall the inputs using JAXB annotations and I am facing some small issues. Wanted to confirm if it's possible to achieve

I have two classes `parent` and `child` each of which has many fields. `child` class extends `parent` class.

1. Is it possible to add the elements from `parent` class in the `child` class `prepOrder` for `@XmlType`?
2. Is it necessary to add all elements within the `propOrder`? for example if I have 10 fields out of which I want only 4 fields to be ordered. Rest can appear in any order they want. Is it possible to do this? Because when I do not add a field then I am getting the error.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Parent",propOrder={"city","year"})
public class Parent{
    private String brand;
    private String city;
    private String year;
    
    //Getters and Setters avoided
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Car")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Child",propOrder={"engine","brand","build"})
public class Child{
    private String engine;
    private String build;
    
    //Getter and Setters avoided
}
```

```
public class Main{
        public static void main(String []args){
        Child child = new Child();
        //Adding values and creating xml using the Marshalling approach
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Child.class);
        Marshaller mar = context.createMarshaller();
        mar.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        mar.marshal(child, System.out);
     }
}
```

The final xml that I am looking forward to is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<child>
    <cit>Frankfurt</cit>
    <year>2021</year>
    <engine>Mercedes</engine>
    <brand>Ferari</brand>
    <build>Germany</build>
</child>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error methods, I was able to do it. Posting the answer as it can be useful to someone else in the future:

1. Add the `@XmlTransient` annotation on the `Parent` class and remove the `propOrder`.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Parent")
@XmlTransient
public class Parent{
//All the parent element fields and other codes getter/setters
}
```

2. Add all the fields in `Child` class which is extending `Parent`

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Car")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Child",propOrder={"city","year","engine","brand","build"})
public class Child{
}
```